# Intercept a click into a twitter button via twitter iframe for internal counter via jquery

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, twitter

Looking to intercept a click into a stock twitter button.  Am attempting to make a note of the click and simply update my on internal counter of these clicks.  By running an ajax request to a page that ratchets up.  Can a click on this iframed element be caught?  Have tried many renditions, here is a stripped down version.  Have tried wrapping the element in divs to no avail.

```
<!-- START TW SHARE --> 
<a id="XXX" href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="." data-text="Join the Challenge &amp; Join now:" data-size="large" data-related="sample data" data-count="none">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
<!-- END TW SHARE -->   

/// VIA JQuery
       $("XXX']").click(function() {
        $.ajax({url: 'plus.php?ID=<?php echo $ID;?>' });
        });
```

Comment: I believe you'll be prevented by the Same Origin Policy

Comment: Yes, I had also tried to place this in a PHP fetch URL, and it worked on fetching, just not on the click.  Seemed to be the same problem with no ID on the iframe to latch onto.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea but I don't know if it will work (never tried). I think if the iframe is not of the same domain the jquery thing won't work. Below is the jquery iframe intercept if it is the same domain

```
<iframe id="myframe" src='/'></iframe>
```

js

```
$('#myframe').contents().find('body').bind('click', function(e) {

   alert('clicked');
});
```

But I don't think this works since twitter is in a different domain so what I was thinking is make a blank page with the twitter button inside of it, then call that page with your iframe and us the code above. Technically you are still clicking on a different domain content but since your original call is of your domain maybe it will register? You can give it a try, I am gonna test this right now. It's a long shot.

Edit: nope didn't work!

Comment: Appreciate the thoughts and your on target.  Have tried this and an issue is that twitter does not ID the iframe (anyway).  Am thinking that there must be some way to capture the coordinates of the click?  I keep trying to place it in a div and capture the inside div click.  Have not succeeded in this type of resolve. Am just trying to get jquery to acknowledge the click - nothing more.

Comment: You don't need the Id of the frame as long as you know where it is on the page... `$("#ContainerDiv iframe").contents().....`. I don't believe setting the contents will help though - otherwise you could create a 100% height/width iframe, point it at a login page and steal passwords

Comment: yea see the answer with the API options, cross domain iframe tracking should not work due to security issues

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the [**Twitter API**](https://dev.twitter.com/docs) to accomplish this.

I would start studying their [**Javascript Events**](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events) which can measure interaction with the tweet button.

**Edit:** In particular, it's the [**click**](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events#click) method that your after:

`Receive an event when the user has clicked the Tweet Button or Follow Button.`

`"tweet" — the click occurred on the Tweet Button itself, invoking an Intent (which will trigger an Intent Event Callback when complete).`